# Sharepoint 2013 custom search refiners

Tags: search, sharepoint-2013

there are some oob types of refiners like slider or slider with graph. I would like to customize a refiner to look like e.g. a treeview. Is there a way I can edit existing ones? Or maybe can I write my own from scratch? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I had in mind...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/murads/archive/2013/03/01/using-jquery-and-jqplot-in-your-display-template-to-show-a-piechart-refiner.aspx